# How to read Microsoft Word Binary Data from database and convert it to readable text

Tags: aspose.words

I'm working in a java application called Mirth where I need to read a saved word document that is saved in a database table in a Microsoft word binary data format. Currently I can retrieve data from column in my java application but I need to convert this to readable text or XML or HTML format.

Looking online there is a java library call Aspose.words but I can't find any methods that would read in this binary data and convert it to something readable. Has anyone use Aspose.words before to do a task like this or does anyone have an alternative solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Load document from Database**

You can load the Word document using ByteArrayInputStream, if it's in a database table. Please refer to http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsjava/How+to++Load+and+Save+a+Document+to+Database for an article that explains saving and reading a Word document to/from database. I have copied the relevant code from there.

```
public static Document readFromDatabase(String fileName) throws Exception
{
    // Create the SQL command.
    String commandString = "SELECT * FROM Documents WHERE FileName='" + fileName + "'";

    // Retrieve the results from the database.
    ResultSet resultSet = executeQuery(commandString);

    // Check there was a matching record found from the database and throw an exception if no record was found.
    if(!resultSet.isBeforeFirst())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(MessageFormat.format("Could not find any record matching the document \"{0}\" in the database.", fileName));

    // Move to the first record.
    resultSet.next();

    // The document is stored in byte form in the FileContent column.
    // Retrieve these bytes of the first matching record to a new buffer.
    byte[] buffer = resultSet.getBytes("FileContent");

    // Wrap the bytes from the buffer into a new ByteArrayInputStream object.
    ByteArrayInputStream newStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer);

    // Read the document from the input stream.
    Document doc = new Document(newStream);

    // Return the retrieved document.
    return doc;

}
```

**Read text**

Once the file is loaded, you can read it's paragraphs, tables, images etc using DOM, see the related documentation at http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsjava/Programming+with+Documents.

But, if you just want to get all the text from a document, you can do it easily by calling toString() method as below

```
System.out.println(doc.toString(SaveFormat.TEXT));
```

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Thanks for this, the error I'm running into is when I query database table that is storing document in a column that is set to a image data type in SQL. I get an error that says **java.sql.SQLException: Data Type Mismatch** , this has when I use 'resultSet.getBytes(1)'. I change the getBytes to getBlob and that got me pass this error. But when I try to get data into InputStream I get this error. **Java constructor for "java.io.ByteArrayInputStream" with arguments "javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob" not found.**

Comment: can you try byte[] buffer = resultSet.getBlob("col-name").getBytes();? It should work with blob types

Comment: Thanks, I got stuck on another project. I try using getBytes() kike you mentioned and i get this error now.

LINE NUMBER: 162
DETAILS: Can't find method javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob.getBytes().

Comment: Just an update, I was able to get this corrected. getBytes() worked. After using a another instance of the data in the primary db I didn't have error anymore.